# Concurrent write to std::vector to different indices causes crash?

Tags: c++, vector, concurrency, mutex

I have a big vector and i want to update some data in that vector (no insert/delete, but rather replacing an element with another on a specified index).

I was thinking that this is pretty clever to do the work on 2 or more different threads, therefore improving the speed. And since no synchronization is really necessary in this case, due to different indices this should be really fast.

Unfortunately my code crashes, either by stating: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, or  "pointer being freed was not allocated".

The pseudocode:

```
// I have an entries_ vector with data of type DataT

std::vector<std::thread> workers(NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_CHUNKS);

unsigned long tuplesPerChunk = entries_.size() / NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_CHUNKS;

for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_CHUNKS; ++j) {
    unsigned long offset = tuplesPerChunk * j;

    workers.emplace_back(std::thread([&offset, &tuplesPerChunk, this](){
        for (int i = 0; i < tuplesPerChunk; ++i) {
            unsigned long offsetIndex = offset + i;
            entries_[offsetIndex] = createNewDataForSomeParticularReason();

        }
    }));
}

for (auto &worker : workers) {
    if (worker.joinable()) worker.join();
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this without more info. Where in the code does the error happen? What have you tried to find out why it's happening? Does it happen with just one thread? With an array of just one entry? etc. Can you make the code substantially simpler and still show the same problem? (in doing so, you will probably figure out what is going wrong.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capture `offset` by value, else you have dangling pointer.

Your threads live from inside the loop until the join.

`offset` only lives inside one loop iteration.

Comment: This works, but can you please elaborate more?

Comment: To be precise `offset` lives inside one loop *iteration*. Each iteration has its own `offset` which disappears as soon as the iteration is over.

Comment: @RustyX Nice catch! Though technically this is undefined behavior, practically the storage for `offset` will likely be reused meaning that threads from past iterations will read the current value of `offset` while the loop is running, introducing a race condition.